# Get console information in c++

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

Okay, i am stuck on how to get console information in c++.  I know how to set things like the color with setConsoleTextAttribute, and the title with setConsoleTitle, but i don't know how to get that information in a method and return it.  I am doing a jni project and i am stuck on this one part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two API calls you are looking for are GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo and GetConsoleTitle, documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: But what do i put in for this PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo

Comment: "lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo [out] - A pointer to a CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO structure that receives the console screen buffer information."  The stuff you need is in the manual page that PeterJ linked to.  And if you click on the link for CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO in that page, it will take you to documentation for the `struct`, etcetera.

Comment: maybe someone could post code for methods that return these things?☺